# Solution Verification: area of sinx and sin2x

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $A$ be the area of region $R$ bounded by $y = \sin(x)$ and $y = \sin(2x)$ over $[0,\pi]$. Calculate the area in this square $[0,\pi]*[-1,1]$ minus the region outside of $R$. Now this was very confusing to figure out, and it appears that the area of $[0,\pi]*[-1,1]$ is a rectangle instead of a square. With that in mind, I calculated the area between the 2 functions $y=\sin(x)$ and $y=\sin(2x)$. The final answer was $2(\pi-1)$. Objections? Any mistakes?

Comment: No.  The area of $R$ should be 5/2.  Note the two curves intersect at $x=\pi/3$.

Comment: @user10354138 Could you expand on that a bit? i want to know where I went wrong. Thanks.

Comment: $\sin(x)<\sin(2x)$ before $x=\pi/3$ and $\sin(x)>\sin(2x)$ after $x=\pi/3$.  So $\int_0^\pi\lvert\sin(x)-\sin(2x)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x$ is not $\int_0^\pi(\sin(x)-\sin(2x))\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area between $\sin(x)$ and $\sin(2x)$ is

$$ A = \int_0^{\pi} {|\sin(2x) - \sin(x)| dx} . $$

To calculate $A$, we first need to determine where the two curves intersect so we can remove the absolute value and integrate. Setting the two functions equal, we have

$$ \sin(2x) = \sin(x) $$
$$ 2\sin(x)\cos(x) = \sin(x) $$
$$ 2\cos(x) = 1 $$
$$ \cos(x) = \frac{1}{2} .$$

On the interval in the question, $[0,\pi]$, this equation has exactly two solutions: $x = 0$ and $x = \pi / 3$. Dividing up our interval into two parts, we can test a random point to determine that $\sin(2x) \ge \sin(x)$ when $x \in [0,\pi / 3]$ and $\sin(x) \ge \sin(2x)$ when $x \in [\pi / 3, \pi]$.

Then, the area between the two curves is

$$ A = \int_0^{\pi} {|\sin(2x) - \sin(x)|  \ dx} $$
$$ = \int_0^{\pi / 3} {\sin(2x) - \sin(x)  \ dx} + \int_{\pi / 3}^{\pi} {\sin(x) - \sin(2x) \ dx} $$
$$ = \left[ -\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x) + \cos(x) \right]_0^{\pi / 3} + \left[ -\cos(x) + \frac{1}{2}\cos(2x) \right]_{\pi / 3}^{\pi} $$
$$ = \frac{5}{2} . $$

Then, the area in the region $[0, \pi] \times [-1, 1]$ outside of $R$ is $ 2\pi - 5/2$.